# Is saying "I am done with my food" proper?

Tags: usage

Today when I was eating, I finished my food and said:

> I am done with my food.

But I am just wondering if the above sentence is proper grammar or not. Of course I can say:

> I am finished with my food.

I think that would sound better of course, but today I said "done with", I am wondering if that is proper.

I also wonder if the below sentence would be proper or not:

> I am almost done with my food.

I think adding "almost" makes it sound more proper and grammatical, but I wonder about if I just said "I am done with my food.".

Comment: Why say anything?  If I am in my office and someone comes in, I don't say "I am sitting on a chair."  Even though it is true and grammatical.  When I finish my lunch, I don't need to tell people the fact ...  Why say anything?  (English doesn't have a set phrase for finishing a meal like (eg) Japanese)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply say

> I'm done. *(I finished)*

(if you are saying it to someone who knows what you are done with, and not on the phone for example). If you wish to be more precise, say rather

> I am done eating. *(I finished eating)*

Addition: The expression ***be done with something*** is not incorrect, it is in fact idiomatic. [M Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20done%20with) defines it as

> to bring to completion, to finish

```
When will you be done with the project?
```

You can also check [Macmillan's](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/be-done-with-it) definition of the expression **be done with it**:

> to have finished dealing with something, so that you do not have to think about it anymore

But in your context, one would rather use the expression [***be done doing something***](https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-translation/be-done-doing#:%7E:text=to%20be%20done%20doing%20something,to%20have%20finished%20doing%20something):

> to have finished (doing something)

For example:

> I'm done Christmas shopping.

If you check this [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be%20done%20eating%2Cbe%20done%20with%20food&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20done%20eating%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20done%20with%20food%3B%2Cc0) you will be convinced that ***to be done eating*** is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, "I've finished eating" or (in context) just "I've finished" would be idiomatic.  "I'm done eating" isn't something most British people would say.

A child who wants to draw attention to their achievement or is looking for permission to move straight on to the next course will say "I've finished!".  But as James K said, an adult will rarely find it necessary to announce that they've finished their meal.  However, this could happen in certain circumstances.  For example, perhaps someone might enter the room and say "Sorry to interrupt your meal" and the other person might reply "No, it's all right, I've just finished."

In a restaurant, a waiter might ask you whether you've finished, but usually only if it isn't obvious (for instance, because some of the food has been left on the plate).  You might reply "Yes" or "Yes, I have" or "Yes, I've finished, thank you."

Similarly, as a guest in someone's home, you normally wouldn't need to tell them you'd finished, but if you did want to draw attention to it, you would probably do so indirectly, by commenting on the quality of the food.  This evaluation should always be positive, regardless of the truth.  For example, "That was a delicious meal - thank you so much."

Even if you hadn't been able to eat everything, you probably still wouldn't need to tell your host that you'd finished (it would be obvious if you put down your knife and fork in the correct formation and didn't eat anything for a while), but if you did, you'd say something like "This really has been a delicious meal, but I'm afraid I can't eat any more."

Comment: Thanks for the answer!